# Command Line in R code

Tags: python, command-line, r

Let me start by saying I am new to programming.

I am hoping to run a python script from the command line within an R script.  I am running windows xp but also have a machine that runs Windows 7.  I can run the following code without error for the dos-prompt.

```
cd C:\Documents and Settings\USER\workspace\UGA - Website
python test1.py
```

I have tried all sorts of different attempts in R using ?system, but am hoping someone can point me to what I am doing wrong.  For example, here is just one attempt (it was recommended to use absolute paths)

```
cmd.1 <- shQuote("C:Python26/python.exe C:/Documents and Settings/USER/Desktop/UGA New Website", type="cmd")
system(cmd.1)
```

Any guidance will be very much appreciated

Comment: Aren't you just missing `/` in `C:Python26..`?

Comment: @Bitbert3: Not tested, but I think since your target path contains spaces you also need to quote that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.  My issue was a combination of things, but this chunk of code worked.

```
shell(paste("python", shQuote("C:\\Documents and Settings\\USER\\Desktop\\UGA New Website\\metrics_get.py")))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a `/` after `C:`, which would make it look like this:

```
cmd.1 <- shQuote("C:Python26/python.exe C:/Documents and Settings/USER/Desktop/UGA New Website", type="cmd")
system(cmd.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but try this:

```
cmd.1 <- shQuote('C:\\Python26\\python.exe "C:\\Documents and Settings\\USER\\Desktop\\UGA New Website"', type="cmd")
system(cmd.1)
```

If this doesn't work, try variations on `\`, `\\` and `/`, and where you put your quotes.

You could also try a system `cd` command to change the directory, so you don't need an absolute path.