# How do i download a file from a download link using R

Tags: r, curl

I have a script that currently downloads a file from a download link that uses Single Signon (SSO) infrastructure. At the moment i'm using a batch script with curl to download it.  How can I make the equalivent all in R to download the file

```
curl negotiate -u user:pass -L --insecure -o DownloadFileName.xml "https://Server/Servlet?param1=value1"
```

Comment: you can use `system()` to [call your system call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745886/r-and-system-calls), or try [`?download.file()`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/download.file)

Comment: @tospig the answer worked

Answer (score 0):

As @tospig suggested use `system()` like so:

```
system("curl negotiate -u user:pass -L --insecure -o DownloadFileName.xml \"https://Server/Servlet?param1=value1\"")
```