# Using R's System to pass multiple arguments to an executable

Tags: r, bash, system

I have read a bit some other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745886/r-and-system-calls) but this seems a bit different:

`coddinggame_DEBUG` takes several arguments. To invoke it in `bash`  with fixed arguments I do:

```
cd /superdirectory/
./codinggame_DDEBUG <<'EOF'
testCases01.txt
1
4
EOF
```

and this works. The bash answers:

```
Enter File name (with extention): Enter seed (unsigned integer): Enter Line Number: Mean Sample:23.3821  Sd Sample:6.19504
```

(no warning and the Mean and Sd are computed correctly)

If I try to achieve the same through `R`:

```
x<-paste0('cd /superdirectory/  \n
./codinggame_DDEBUG <<"EOF"     \n
testCases01.txt                 \n
1                               \n
4                               \n
EOF                             \n
echo done')
cat(x)
system(x)
```

I get:

```
Enter File name (with extention): Enter seed (unsigned integer): Warning:1
```

e.g. The second argument ('1') is not passed properly which causes the code to stop there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
x<-paste0('cd /superdirectory/  \n
    >input.txt echo testCases01.txt                     \n
    >>input.txt echo 1                          \n
    >>input.txt echo 4                      \n
    ./codinggame_DDEBUG <input.txt                  \n
    echo done')
    cat(x)

system(x)
```