# How to call linux terminal code from R script

Tags: r, linux, system-calls

My question is:

## How can I call a Linux Terminal inside a **R script**?

I know it can be a silly question... my R code is here:

```
download.file('https://some.dir,
              destfile = '/home/myfile.grb2',method='auto',quiet = FALSE,
              mode="wb", cacheOK = TRUE)
```

after the download, I had to convert that file using a code from terminal... but I need this to be automatic. The converter code is this:

```
source activate ncl_stable
cd /home
ncl_convert2nc myfile.grb2
```

Googling I saw that **Linux Terminal** uses **C++**. I know there is a package to run C++ codes in to R, **Rcpp**, but it works like the linux terminal?

Comment: You can use [`system`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
system(paste0("source activate ncl_stable;cd /home;ncl_convert2nc myfile.grb2"))
```

You can find more information [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745886/r-and-system-calls).

Comment: How is `paste0` necessary here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In
`source activate ncl_stable`
it gaves
`sh: 2: source: not found`
Then it executes the rest of the code but an error occurs:
`fatal:NclGRIB2: Invalid Product Definition Template.`
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
When I execute this code on Linux Bash, it gave a list of nor recognized formats like this
`ERROR 4: /vsimem/work.jpc not recognized as a supported file format.`

`dec_jpeg2000: Unable to open JPEG2000 image within GRIB file.`
But the script runs and convert the file, in R don't.

Comment: I tried some combinations, and the problem is in the first line, when executing `source activate ncl_stable` and the error: `sh: 2: source: not found` There is a lot of information... im looking what's the problem now.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really help you with this. It might be better adressed in a separate new question.

Comment: I'm sorry I have mislead you. It was a rhetorical question stating that `paste0` is not really necessary. As it is, it might give someone with little experience the feeling that it's needed, while it's really not.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik sorry for the harsh response :) I am used to wrap my strings in paste statements because I usually concatenate them with variables. But you are right, in this case it might confuse people :)