# How can I call a Windows Terminal inside an R script?

Tags: r, windows, cdo-climate

I need to call a Windows Terminal inside a R script,
I asked a similar question before, but using a Linux Terminal:
[How to call linux terminal code from R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235693/how-to-call-linux-terminal-code-from-r-script)

I am using cdo (Climate Data Operators) in Linux, inside a R code

```
system(paste0("cd ~/Data/; cdo -f nc copy file1.grb2 file2.nc;"))
```

The answer in Linux is so simple, and it did the trick perfect. How can I do this in Windows?

Comment: You can also use `system()` on Window. What exactly did you try and what didn't work. If you need to run run OS commands rather than programs, you can use `shell()` instead

Comment: yes, perhaps an error report might help us to see what the issue is?