# Ubuntu terminal from R in Windows10

Tags: r, windows, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Recently (2017) Windows 10 provides an official Ubuntu subsystem that works perfectly (It is not a Virtual Machine or an app like Cywin). This Ubuntu subsystem inside Windows provides the classic linux shell.

I am using CDO (Climate Data Operators) from an R script in my Ubuntu laptop  using the system() command.

```
system(paste0("cd ~/Data/; cdo -f nc copy file1.grb2 file2.nc;"))
```

but I need to run my code in Windows computers.

I asked before how to use this system() command from R inside Windows here: [How can I call a Windows Terminal inside an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029830/how-can-i-call-a-windows-terminal-inside-an-r-script?noredirect=1#comment94896020_54029830) and I learned that it is the same as in Ubuntu.

But what I need is different: How to call the Ubuntu Shell in an R script in Windows 10?

I've thought about using some type of composition like

```
System(some-command-that-calls-ubuntu-terminal())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can try with the `wsl`command.
wsl stands for windows subsystem for linux and if you type it in a cmd shell it will open the linux shell. In an R environment (on Windows) type:

```
shell(cmd="wsl")
```

Or if you want to execute more, e.g.

```
>shell(cmd="wsl ls")
Documents
Images
...
```

Does this help?