# Automate Git bash in r

Tags: r, bash, git

I have an r-script that I run once a week. Once that script is complete I go through the normal routine of doing the following:

1) Run script

2) open Git Bash

3) going to my directory in git bash:

cd/Documents

cd/webiste

cd/r-projects

4) then I write git add -A

5) git commit -m "today's date"

6) git push

This is a weekly task and I want to be able to automate this.

Has anyone done this in the past?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: If you are using linux, you can have a cron take care of both runing the R script and the git commits.

Comment: If you are on Windows (guessing from your usage of Git Bash), you can use Task Scheduler to automate that. Less elegant than cron but does the job.

Comment: Also, in case you want to stay completely in R, you can pass all the bash commands to `system()`

Comment: Hi @ozacha I like where you are going with the latter comment for completely staying in R. Can you go further into detail with that or provide a link to continue my research on this? Thanks

Comment: See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/system or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745886/r-and-system-calls